# I want to Fetch data from a specific Field in Chunks

Tags: sql

I have query as

```
SELECT SUBSTR('GENERAL - COMPUTERS - COMPUTER WORKSTATION', 1, (INSTR('GENERAL - COMPUTERS - COMPUTER WORKSTATION', '-')-1)) first, 
substr('GENERAL - COMPUTERS - COMPUTER WORKSTATION', instr('GENERAL - COMPUTERS - COMPUTER WORKSTATION', '-') + 1) second
from mtl_categories_v
where segment1 = '01';
```

it give the result as :

```
first                 second
GENERAL    COMPUTERS - COMPUTER WORKSTATION
```

but I want query that give result as

```
first                 second                            third
GENERAL              COMPUTERS                 COMPUTER WORKSTATION
```

please tell me the way to fetch characters before and after dashes.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? In Postgres you can simply use `string_to_array()`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using MySQL:

```
SELECT TRIM(SUBSTRING_INDEX(col, '-', 1)) AS first,
       TRIM(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(col, '-', 2), '-', -1)) AS second,
       TRIM(SUBSTRING_INDEX(col, '-', -1)) AS third
FROM mtl_categories_v
WHERE segment1 = '01';
```

**Demo here:**

## Rextester